# Propel filterBy not work?

Tags: propel

Im trying test if an username already exists. But always return "username exists":

```
   if (!isset($_POST['usuario'])) {
    /* Parameters not pass */
    exit("{'success': false, 'msg': 'No hay parametros.'}");
   }

   /* Search a user with username == $_POST['usuario'] */
   $usuarioCohincidente = UsuariosQuery::create()
                          ->filterByNombreusuario($_POST['usuario'])
                          ->find();

   if($usuarioCohincidente->isEmpty()){
       /* Username is available */
       exit("{'success': false, 'msg':'Usuario inexistente.'}");
   }else{
      /* Username is not available */
      exit("{'success': true, 'msg': 'Usuario existente, por favor, seleccione otro      nombre para el usuario.'}");
   }
```

Any idea ?.

Comment: I catch the error. I not sent correctly the params via POST. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should try

`$usuarioCohincidente = UsuariosQuery::create()
                          ->filterByNombreusuario($_POST['usuario'])
                          ->findOne();`

not `find()` cause it won't returns object but array containing object.

Don't check my method `isEmpty()`, use `if($usuarioCohincidente == null)`.

All in all, please include `var_dump` of your object to be sure you're doing the right thing.